# Java - Full Screen JFrame is not shown on Print Screen/Screen recordings?

Tags: java, jframe, screen, frame, fullscreen

I was wondering what might be the cause of the problem? So basically.. When I run my program the JFrame pops up, but if I try to record it using Print Screen or Skype Screenshare or anything like that the JFrame is not shown? It is fullscreen JFrame.

```
package com.game;

import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame {
final String title = "";
static GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0];

public Frame(){
    setTitle(title);
    setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    Screen.Width = getWidth();
    Screen.Height = getHeight();
    setResizable(false);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
    Screen screen = new Screen(this); //Screen is a JPanel.
    add(screen);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame = new Frame();

}
}
```

All the help is greatly Appreciated. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem just remove the:

```
device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
```